# Flex charting component --- matrix diagrams

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, charts, data-visualization

I am currently using Protovis library (which uses JavaScript and SVG) for my charting application. Because of problems of SVG support in IE I would like to use Flex for all of the charts. Does anyone know of any Flex charting component which similar to a matrix diagram using Protovis?
Here is a link of Protovis matrix diagram:
http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

For this, you could use Flex and [axiis](http://www.axiis.org/examples.html) which is a tool to make complex charts based on [degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/)

Cheers